# "If he come" vs. "If he comes"

Tags: grammar, mood

I've found the following on the internet (https://www.jstor.org/stable/43344096) :

> (1). If he comes, I shall go.
>
> (2). If he come, I shall go.

Here, the first sentence is in **indicative mood**, and the second one is in **subjunctive mood**.

What's the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

**Edit**: Though the second sentence seems ungrammatical to me, I have also found these in a school grammar book, "The Best Guide for Madhyamik English" by A. K. Chatterjee. Therefore, I would like to know what the native speakers think of these.

Comment: In order for the second sentence to be grammatical, it needs to be *if he **should** come …*

Comment: The source is : https://www.jstor.org/stable/43344096  I've also found these in a school grammar book : "The Best Guide for Madhyamik English" by A. K. Chatterjee.

Comment: However, I looked at the abstract and I did not see the fragment sentence which you said you found on the Internet, i.e. **If he come, I shall go** Please clarify if the example(s) comes from the study cited or from the textbook "Madhyamik English".

Comment: Google produces **only 7 results** for ["If he come, I shall go"](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk009Y0mncEfA6zSkYPSv271nCqyvUw%3A1590314466363&ei=4kXKXo3kFeaCk74PiJy40AY&q=+%22if+he+come%2C+I+shall+go%22&oq=+%22if+he+come%2C+I+shall+go%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB5Q0W9Y0W9g73FoAHAAeACAAXCIAXCSAQMwLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiN3eSGn8zpAhVmwcQBHQgODmoQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) My vote to close this question remains.

Comment: Yes, the example mainly comes from the textbook that I've mentioned. Then, I searched on the internet and found that jstor article. I'm looking forward to a good answer from an expert as well as a native speaker of English.

Comment: That particular construction (_if_ clause with infinitive) has been obsolete in American English since about 1800. And gods only know what nonsense has been put into purported English textbooks destined for non-native speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consistent with its non-factual status, the *if...* verb may be in the plain form, marking the subjunctive construction. Subjunctive in conditionals is rare, especially with verb-forms other than *be*. It belongs to the formal style and verges on archaic. (CaGEL p1000)

In the first sentence *if he comes* is an open conditional: his coming is not viewed as unlikely. In the second *if he come* also falls into the category of open conditionals, and similarly the speaker would not think his coming unlikely (CaGEL p745).

So, it seems there is little difference in meaning, but a clear difference in style: the first being idiomatic present-day English, and the second being formal or even archaic.

To my ears, the second sounds absolutely unacceptable in any context whatsoever.

Comment: Definitely archaic.